# Area Under a Curve, Given is the Data

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was looking  for the area under the curve determined by the given data.

$$\begin {array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline x &2&5&8&11&14&17&20\\\hline y&4.16&3.98&3.31&2.86 &3.02&3.61 &4.34\\\hline\end {array}$$

My work:

Using the Simpson's Rule:

$$\int _b ^a y dx = \frac{h}{3} \left(y_0 + 4y_1 + 2y_2 + 4y_3 +2y_4 +...+4y_{n-1} + y_n \right )$$

where $h = \frac{b-a}{n}$

Then, plugging in the values found in the given data to the Simpson's rule formula:

$$\int _2 ^{20} y dx = \frac{h}{3} \left(4.16 + 4(3.98) + 2(3.31) + 4(2.86) + 2(3.02) + 4(3.61) + 4.34 \right )$$

where $h = \frac{20-2}{7} = \frac{18}{7}$

which gives the answer

$$\frac{\frac{18}{7}}{3} \left(4.16 + 4(3.98) + 2(3.31) + 4(2.86) + 2(3.02) + 4(3.61) + 4.34 \right ) = 53.9657 $$

The answer found in my book is $62.96$. How do you get the value of $62.96$?
My solution seems legit.....

Comment: or you could just used MathJaX again : $$\begin {array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline x &2&5&8&11&14&17&20\\\hline y&4.16&3.98&3.31&2.86 &3.02&3.61 &4.34\\\hline\end {array}$$

Comment: In your text, are the trapezoid rule or left/right endpoint rules covered? (might be one of them)

Comment: @coffeemath Yes I did. My starting point is $P(x, y) = P(2, 4.16)$ and my ending point is $P(x, y) = P(20, 4.34)$. I got it covered XD

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee oh..I gotta practice doing that...heheh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are seven points of data, but six intervals. Ergo, $n=6$. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Yehey! It solved my problem. But where can I see this "six intervals"? I like to see it........because I only see 7 points of data.

Comment: @PalautotKa If you take two points there is one interval between. Three points give two intervals between, etc.